# Putting a variable into a form using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, css-selectors

This is pretty plain and simple but I'm just scratching my head.
I created a form (https://taa.be.wolterskluwer.com/l/940253/2021-10-08/5tgp6n) which contains a field GACLIENTID (I've assigned it the classes GA_Client_ID & GACLIENTID) however since the form is not handcoded the class is assigned to the contacting paragraph (which contains a label & input).

I've successfully pushed my variable using the following script:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="940253_168501pi_940253_168501"]');
    list.forEach(function(el){
      if(el) {
        el.value = {{DL - GA Client ID}};
  }
})
  })();
</script>
```

But this finds the input with the "name" of the field which changes on every clone of the form I'm creating. So I'm looking for a more "universal" way of selecting the input within the class but I just can't, for the life of me, figure out the correct syntax.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.GACLIENTID input');
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy, thanks ever so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If there's only ever one matching field.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.GACLIENTID input');

if (input) {
    input.value = {{DL - GA Client ID}};
}
```

Comment: I'll have to try this as well as I think it's just as good. Can you explain what the "?" before the .value declaration does? (Just trying to learn as long as I'm here )

Comment: Sure thing, but I do have to update the answer as it does not work in this context, sorry. (You cannot use this operator on the left hand of an assignment.) It is an optional chaining operator. If the value at that point is null/undefined, it will short circuit the evaluation (preventing a null/undefined reference error), instead returning undefined. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)